# Calculating percentages with GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table with 3 columns which looks like this:

```
File    User     Rating (1-5)
------------------------------
00001    1        3
00002    1        4
00003    2        2
00004    3        5
00005    4        3
00005    3        2
00006    2        3
Etc.
```

I want to generate a query that outputs the following (for each user and rating, display the number of files as well as percentage of files):

```
User    Rating   Count   Percentage
-----------------------------------
1       1         3      .18
1       2         6      .35
1       3         8      .47
2       5         12     .75
2       3         4      .25
```

With Postgresql, I know how to create a query that includes the first 3 columns using the following query, but I can't figure out how to calculate percentage within the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
    User,
    Rating,
    Count(*)
FROM
    Results
GROUP BY
    User, Rating
ORDER BY
    User, Rating
```

Here I want the percentage calculation to apply to each user/rating group.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
WITH t1 AS 
 (SELECT User, Rating, Count(*) AS n 
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY User, Rating)
SELECT User, Rating, n, 
       (0.0+n)/(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY User)) -- no integer divide!
FROM t1;
```

Or

```
SELECT User, Rating, Count(*) OVER w_user_rating AS n, 
        (0.0+Count(*) OVER w_user_rating)/(Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY User)) AS pct
FROM your_table
WINDOW w_user_rating AS (PARTITION BY User, Rating);
```

I would see if one of these or the other yields a better query plan with the appropriate tool for your RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I slightly modified version of your second query worked:

`select user, rating, cnt, cnt::float * 100/(sum(cnt) over (partition by user)) from (select user, rating, count(*) as cnt from tbl group by user, rating) a order by user,rating`

Comment: Do you need to use SUM(COUNT(*)) in both examples?  Something like `(SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY User))` in the first example? With SUM I get the expected values, otherwise I'm dividing by the number of Ratings instead of the sum of their counts.

Comment: @TylerDeWitt, I think so, see DeadMonkey's comment above.

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, you can do the old-school way — arguably easier to grok:

```
select usr.User                   as User   ,
       usr.Rating                 as Rating ,
       usr.N                      as N      ,
       (100.0 * usr.N) / total.N as Pct
from ( select User, Rating , count(*) as N
       from Results
       group by User , Rating
     ) usr
join ( select User , count(*) as N
       from Results
       group by User
     ) total on total.User = usr.User
order by usr.User, usr.Rating
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! This works too without using window functions. I had to change "item" to "usr" in the query above and remove the first count(*).

Answer (score 5):

In TSQL this should work

```
SELECT
    User,
    Rating,
    Count(*), SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY User, Rating ORDER BY User, Rating) AS Total,
Count(*)/(SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY User, Rating ORDER BY User, Rating)) AS Percentage
FROM
    Results
GROUP BY
    User, Rating
ORDER BY
    User, Rating
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this would be with [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html).

Comment: would you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH data AS 
 (SELECT User, Rating, Count(*) AS Count 
  FROM Results
  GROUP BY User, Rating)
SELECT User, Rating, Count, 
       (0.0+n)/(SUM(Count) OVER (PARTITION BY User))
FROM data;
```

Comment: What is n here ? I tried this out, but I could not make it work

Answer (score 0):

If data is not too big, you might consider subqueries for ease of use. Make sure subquery queries same data.

```
SELECT User, [Rating], Count(*) AS COUNT,
100.0* (COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Results) as 'Percentage'
FROM Results
GROUP BY User, [Rating]
```

I tested this on a similar table

```
select OrderStatus, Count(*) as Antall,
CASE 
    WHEN OrderStatus = 0 THEN 'Bestilt (Ordered'
    WHEN OrderStatus = 1 THEN 'Besvart (Completed)'
    WHEN OrderStatus = 2 THEN 'Utløpt (Expired)'
    WHEN OrderStatus = 3 THEN 'Feilet (Error)'
    WHEN OrderStatus = 4 THEN 'Ikke bestilt (NotOrdered)'
    WHEN OrderStatus = 5 THEN 'Fysisk post returnert uåpnet (PhysicalMailReturned)'
    WHEN OrderStatus = 6 THEN 'Prosesserer bestilling (Processing)'
    WHEN OrderStatus = 7 THEN 'Deleted (Slettet)'
END AS OrderStatusText,
100 * (COUNT(*) *1.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PromsFormOrder where created >= '2023-11-29')) as 'Percentage rate'
FROM PromsFormOrder
where Created >= '2023-11-29'
GROUP BY OrderStatus
```

The fiddling with multiplying with 1.0 here is to make sure we switch to floating based arithmetic so our percentages are not 0 or 1 due to integer division.

[image: Grouped data - calculate percentage]

Using partitions over or windowed functions are probably faster than subqueries, but syntax is using more well-known constructs of SQL. The Rating column is a reserved word in T-SQL (SQL Server) so I had to use [Rating], in Postgres this is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions on top of aggregate functions:

```
select
    user,
    rating,
    count(*) as total_per_user_rating_tuple,
    sum(count(*)) over (partition by user) as total_per_user,
    count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by user) as subtotal_upon_total_per_user
from results
group by user, rating
order by user, rating
```

The query will work in any RDBMS that implements analytic (window) functions. Notice that aggregate functions are nested inside analytic functions. This works because of the order of operations in SQL.

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FUf54kcz)