# Show Percentages for Week and Year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this sql syntax, which works great. It shows the count of sources utilized to get to us. I want the number to be shown in percentages (out of 100%) rather than in count. How can I get my statement to show the count in percentages, please provide help Databasers.

statement:

```
select coalesce(t2.Source, 'Total') as "Source", 
       coalesce(count(case when Week = date_trunc('week', now())::date - 1
                                then t1."Source" end),0) "This Week", 
       coalesce(count(t1.Source),0) "YTD"
from infosys t2 
     left join infocentertracker t1 
               ON t1.Source = t2.Source
               and Week >= DATE '01/01/2017' 
               and Week < DATE '01/01/2018'
               and Project_ID = 'PCR'
group by rollup(t2.Source)
```

Result:

```
Source           This Week    YTD                      This Week     YTD
Billboard          0           0                          0%          0%
Builder            2           8                         20%         12%
Community Website  0           2                          0%          3%
Drive-by           6           35                        60%         52%
Non-Disclosed      0           1       Requested -->      0%          2%
Other Website      0           4                          0%          6%
Radio              0           0                          0%          0%
Realtor            1           13                        10%         19%
Resident Referral  1           3                         10%          4%
Return Visitor     0           0                          0%          0%
RPG Website        0           0                          0%          0%
Social Media       0           2                          0%          3%
Total             10           68                        100%        100%
```

Comment: why are you using `by rollup`?

Comment: To show the Total at the bottom of the query.

Comment: Perhaps a window function is needed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6207658/3430807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way, but you can use the existing query as a sub-query to get the required result in percentage using the `MAX` window function.

```
SELECT Source,
ROUND(100.0*"This Week"/ MAX(CASE WHEN Source='Total' THEN "This Week" END) OVER(),0)||'%' AS "This Week",
ROUND(100.0*YTD/ MAX(CASE WHEN Source='Total' THEN YTD END) OVER(),0)||'%' AS YTD
FROM
 (SELECT COALESCE(T2.Source, 'Total') AS "Source",
          COALESCE(COUNT(CASE
                             WHEN WEEK = DATE_TRUNC('week', NOW())::date - 1 THEN T1."Source"
                         END),0) "This Week",
          COALESCE(COUNT(T1.Source),0) "YTD"
  FROM INFOSYS T2
  LEFT JOIN INFOCENTERTRACKER T1 ON T1.Source = T2.Source
  AND WEEK >= DATE '01/01/2017'
  AND WEEK < DATE '01/01/2018'
  AND PROJECT_ID = 'PCR'
  GROUP BY ROLLUP(T2.Source)
  ) X
```

Comment: Thanks vkp, the first select I tried `t1.Source` and it threw out an error, `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t1"`. Any idea on how I can tackle this.

Comment: i edited it again..i assume `source` is case sensitive. Please modify it accordingly in the inner query with the exact case of that column in either of the tables. I used `Source`..

Comment: you are only selecting one source in the inner query from table t2. that is being selected in the outer query as well. you don't need an alias to refer to it.

Comment: you should just concatenate a `%`. added it as well.