# How to calculate the percentage of values with grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have table:

```
Country:
id | name     | group| type
1  | USA      | 1    | 0
2  | Germany  | 2    | 1
3  | France   | 2    | 0
4  | China    | 1    | 1
5  | Japan    | 3    | 0
6  | Italy    | 1    | 1
7  | Mexico   | 1    | 0
8  | Columbia | 3    | 0
9  | Taiwan   | 2    | 1
...
```

Now I would like receive percentange of positive "type" with grouped by "group" field.

So results should looks like:

```
group| percentage
1    | 50%        -- 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 2/4 = 50%
2    | 66%        -- 1 + 0 + 1 = 2/3 = 66%
3    | 0%         -- 0 + 0 = 0/2 = 0%
```

How is the best way for this? Is this possible in one query? I am newbie in MySQL and I don't have any idea. I can only:

```
SELECT group, (????) as percentage FROM country GROUP BY group;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating percentages with GROUP BY query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207224/calculating-percentages-with-group-by-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column type has only the values 0 and 1:

```
SELECT 
  `group`, 
  round(100.0 * sum(type) / count(*), 0) as percentage 
FROM country 
GROUP BY `group`;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nm693fJohiLCVAFnGSS56k/0).
Results:

```
| group | percentage |
| ----- | ---------- |
| 1     | 50         |
| 2     | 67         |
| 3     | 0          |
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `AVG`

```
SELECT group, round(avg(type*100.0), 0) as percentage 
FROM country 
GROUP BY group
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2b83152959116ca32957636e3adec9f)