# TSQL - Return a percentage, when using a group without grouping on percentage columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've searched everywhere and cannot find what I'm looking for. I pull a data set into two temp tables broken down by day. In one of the selects off the temp tables I need to group by week. This causes a problem because it breaks my percentages. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how I can get the below query to execute with the selected group by options.

```
Select datepart(wk,ts.TotalDate) AS Date,
       Tender_Type,
       SUM(TransactionsbyType),
       SUM(TotalDayTransactions),
       ROUND(TransactionsbyType * 100.0 / TotalDayTransactions, 3),
       ROUND(TenderAmountAuthorized * 100.0 / TotalDayAuthAmount, 3) AS 'PercentOfSalesByTenderType'
from  #TotalSalesByOrderingSystem tso
join #TotalSales ts on ts.TotalDate = tso.TotalOrderingSysDate 
group by  datepart(wk,ts.TotalDate), Tender_Type  
order by  datepart(wk,ts.TotalDate), Tender_Type
```

When executed query returns a failure stating that the columns used to get the percentage `TransactionsbyType`  and `TotalDayTransactions` are not in the aggregate.

If I place them in the aggregate the data is not collapsed properly into weeks. I've previously tried the solutions here unsuccessfully: [stackoverflow.com/questions/6207224/calculating-percentages-with-group-by-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207224/calculating-percentages-with-group-by-query/6207658)

Comment: Are the percentages supposed to be by day or for the whole table?

Comment: @Nick My hope is to get the percentages by week. currently when this query executes (with the unwanted columns in the group by), it shows the percentages broken down by days due to the extra fields in the grouping. Then it shows the date as a week. Basically, instead of having only three rows for a given week, I could have up to 21. The source temp tables have multiple months worth of data by date, so I can't pull from the whole table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the percentages over the same period, you just need to use the same `SUM`s in those computations:

```
Select datepart(wk,ts.TotalDate) AS Date,
       Tender_Type,
       SUM(TransactionsbyType),
       SUM(TotalDayTransactions),
       ROUND(SUM(TransactionsbyType) * 100.0 / SUM(TotalDayTransactions), 3),
       ROUND(SUM(TenderAmountAuthorized) * 100.0 / SUM(TotalDayAuthAmount), 3) AS 'PercentOfSalesByTenderType'
from  #TotalSalesByOrderingSystem tso
join #TotalSales ts on ts.TotalDate = tso.TotalOrderingSysDate 
group by  datepart(wk,ts.TotalDate), Tender_Type  
order by  datepart(wk,ts.TotalDate), Tender_Type
```