# How to take % value for Line graph for series Groups ?/How to plot graph by sql table?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

## Approach 1:How to take % value for Line graph for series Groups?

I am setting up a ssrs report like with x axis(Category Group) as Finished Week, QualityPercent( as Series groups-RFT%,REwork%,Scrap%) and Values as Sum of Quantity.
[image]

In the above graph the quatities are shown in percentages based upon weeks(the actual result whose plot values are given at left side of image). Respective tables structure:
[image]
But I am getting the chart like this
[image]

Here the y axis is not plotting well asper the category values, sometimes shoots upto 250%!! or 1400% !!! (this is embarrassing).

For the above graph i used expression as:
IIF(Sum(Fields!QTY.Value,"Chart11_SeriesGroup"),Sum(Fields!QTY.Value)/Sum(Fields!QTY.Value, "DataSet_Production"),0)
What i am missing? I even used #Percent. Kindly help me.

## Approach 2: How to plot the ssrs graph using below result from sql query?

```
FinishedWeek    QualityPercent  QTY   Percentage
1                 Rework (%)    844   0.109724
1                 RFT (%)       6811  0.885465
1                 Scrap (%)      37   0.004810
2                 Rework (%)    742   0.094618
2                 RFT (%)       7096  0.904871
2                 Scrap (%)      4    0.000510
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much work done with second approach, I wrote the separate query for the above table
asper the link: 
[Calculating percentage within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823599/calculating-percentage-within-a-group)

```
select t1.FinishedWeek,t1.QualityPercent,Sum(QTY) as QTY,Sum(QTY)/ t2.TOTAL_QTY  as Percentage   from @temp 
AS t1
  JOIN (
    select FinishedWeek,Sum(QTY) as TOTAL_QTY   from @temp
    group by FinishedWeek
  ) AS t2
  ON t1.FinishedWeek= t2.FinishedWeek
 group by t1.FinishedWeek,QualityPercent,t2.TOTAL_QTY
```

From above query , took the Finished Week as Category, QTY as Values, and QualityPercent as Series Groups