# Get out procentage out of mongodb aggreate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to mongodb and I'm trying to get my mongodb aggreagt correct, but I'm missing something.
I want this search to get procentage from specific playername.

I found this post and I have tried to replicate this but I don't have the same data.

[Calculating percentage within a group in mongodb aggregate pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157608/calculating-percentage-within-a-group-in-mongodb-aggregate-pipeline)

This is a exemple of how my collection looks like:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"630b25bc2256457d80760ec4"},"playersName":"yoyo","playersChoice":"Paper"}

{"_id":{"$oid":"630720244e62a26b17f38d03"},"playersChoice":"Scissor","playersName:":"nicklas"}

{"_id":{"$oid":"63071eca4e62a26b17f38d02"},"playersChoice":"Paper","playersName:":"nicklas"}
```

[sampledata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59YBp.png)

Right now I get zero back

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code where I am grouping by players name and counting the total for paper and scissor.

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        playersName: "$playersName"
      },
      playersChoice: {
        "$addToSet": "$playersChoice"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        playersChoice: "$playersChoice"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$total"
      }
    }
  }
])
```